# Angular 1: communications between transcluded repeated directives?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I faced with a problem.

I want to create tabs with separated navigation and content (each one is a separate directive), they are talking to each other using events.

So, the navigations directive is pretty easy, I didn't include this part here. But the content is much more difficult to me. I want to show only a selected tab and hide others (based on some variable in parent `tabs`' scope). Each tab can contain directive/expression/plain html. I tried plenty of variants but they didn't work.

Could you please help me to find a solution?

1. How to pass a variable `{{item.key}}` to an attribute for ng-repeated ng-transcluded directives? Like `<tab key="{{item.key}}" repeat="item in items">`
2. How to access a variable `selectedTabKey` (that is in `tabs` directive) from every child tab's scope?

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
var $ = angular.element;

app.run(function($templateCache, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.items = [ 
    {key:1,value:'a'},
    {key:2,value:'b'},
    {key:3,value:'c'}
  ];
});

app.directive( "tabs", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      scope.selectedTabKey = 2;
      // TODO: changing the selectedTabKey value
      // want to show/hide the related tab
    }
  };
});

app.directive( "tab", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: "<div><span transclude></span></div>",
    link: function( scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude ) {
      var transc = $(elem[0].querySelector( "[transclude]" ));
      transclude( scope, function( childs ) {
        transc.append( childs );
      });
      transc.attr("ng-repeat", attr.repeat);
      $compile(transc)(scope);
      // todo: access parent's var `selectedTabKey`
      // and make visible the related tab 
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <tabs>
    <!-- how to pass the attr {{item.key}} below? -->
    <tab key="{{item.key}}" repeat="item in items">
      <!-- here some directive/expression/plain html -->
      {{item.value}}
    </tab>
  </tabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Used a `require` in directive's configs.

Here is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/IGrgb5GY5legl2ncrw2d?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Friend,
You can't see that variable "selectedTabKey" in "tab" link because of cycle digest, you have two alternatives:

1. Put "tabs" in a pre link to run before.

   `link: {
       pre:function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
         scope.selectedTabKey = 2;
         // TODO: changing the selectedTabKey value
         // want to show/hide the related tab
       }
   }`

***OR***

2. Put creation of element in next digest cycle using a $timeout

   `app.directive( "tab", function($compile, $timeout) {
       ...
       link: function( scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude ) {
       ...
           $timeout(function(){
               console.log(scope.$parent.selectedTabKey)
           },0)
       }
   }`

Comment: The second option looks good, but unfortunately doesn't work.. Here is the code https://plnkr.co/edit/7xw2Zhh95CxvKzADOSXd?p=preview Any ideas?

Comment: The first one doesn't work neither https://plnkr.co/edit/A9cXRGw7cxcMwCVu13st?p=preview

Comment: sorry, for both try to remove isolate scope  (remove "scope:true")

Comment: Thank you! That did help! But there is another point in the question above - how to better pass the value of item in attribute?

Comment: Finally, I found a solution.